# Spring Application takes too much time

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-mvc

I had written a SpringMVC code to export PostgreSQL databases to ndjson files, The code works. However, One of the tables take like 10seconds ( Careplan ) for 100 records !

the following is the code for DAO class

```
public List<DafCarePlanParticipant> getCarePlanparticipantByCareTeam(int id) 
{
        Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(DafCarePlanParticipant.class, "dp").add(Restrictions.eq("careteam", id));

        List<DafCarePlanParticipant> dafCareTeam = criteria.list();

        return dafCareTeam;
}
```

I've running into deadends without any success of optimizing this code. Can i get some help, please!

Thank you !

Comment: What does `getSession` do. How complex is your `DafCarePlanParticipant` (is it really one table or half of the DB with all the relations in there) and do you really need to retrieve everything (that is what `list` is doing) why not lazily fetch things (using the `stream` method).

Comment: If you don't have an index on the column `careteam` and your table is sufficiently large, that's the kind of behaviour that you should expect. If that's the cause, create on an index on column `careteam`.

Comment: How do i do that sir? Lazy fetching .

Comment: I'm not going to review your code for you (or do your work). So I'm not going to download the code and look at it (if you think it adds to your question add code (snippets) to your question instead). Also get a profiler and check what is taking up the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem maybe due to `getSession()`. Since `getSession()` might create a new Session, it consumes time to create a new session every time and exhaust your datasource.

Try to use `getCurrentSession()` instead to see if any improvement.

Comment: I will give it a try !